# sql update error using php

Tags: php, sql, database, forms, web

I keep getting

Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving <strike>https://www.website.com/update.php?FName=asdd&PHONE=4444444444</strike>. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

```
<?php

    $FName = $_POST['FName'];
    $LName = $_POST['LName'];
    $PHON = $_POST['PHON'];

    //connect
    $dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "username", "password") or die ('ERROR!');
    mysql_select_db ("user_Client"); 

    $query = "INSERT INTO ClientTable (ID, FName, LName, PHON) VALUES 
                ('NULL','".$FName."','".$LName."','".$PHON."')";

    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating Daatabase');
    echo "Database Update with:" .$FName. " " .$LName. " " .$PHON. ;
?>
```

I don't know what's the problem here. I followed instructions from here http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php#.UEiSQY3iajk
If it helps - I'm using cPanel from Josthost.

Here is the form:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title></title>
        </head>

        <body>
                <form method="post" action="update.php">
                        First Name:<br/>
                        <input type="text" name="FName" size="30" /><br/>
                        Last Name:<br/>
                        <input type="text" name="LName" size="30" /><br/>
                        Phone:<br/>
                        <input type="text" name="PHON" size="12" /><br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Update Database"/>
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Is ID set to allow nulls? What does your schema look like?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what does SQL has to do with a 404?

Comment: @Mihai Iorga: Don't assume that he/she has access to latest and greatest PHP. It may be that they are working on a legacy system.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your error, but you're setting `$FNLame` and trying to use `$LName` other places. Lots of other errors too though...

Comment: Are you sure you want to save post variables? From the URL it looks like you need get variables, such as $_GET['FName'] etc.

Comment: Your code is riddled with errors. Do not use `$_POST` the way you do. At least escape them before you put them in the query.

Comment: sorry about that ok i fixed it but still it doesn't update on the database just creates empty tables

Comment: @AndrewSledge if he/she posted here a question here then he/she has access to the most advanced `PHP` solutions that are out there!

Comment: @Mihai  I have to aggree with you on that!

Comment: problem is fixed thank you for your contributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement is wrong:

```
echo "Database Update with:" .$FName. " " .$LName. " " .$PHON. ;
```

Should be (without the last dot):

```
echo "Database Update with:" .$FName. " " .$LName. " " .$PHON ;
```

If you look in the error log of your webserver, you'll be able to see the error. Another idea could be to turn on errors in PHP in either `php.ini` or with `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`. Make sure you only do that on your development system though.

Comment: See the other answers for that. Use `$_REQUEST['PHONE']` instead of `$_POST['PHON']`

Comment: Also, don't write `'NULL'` in the ID field. If it is auto-increment, just don't refer to it: `$query = "INSERT INTO ClientTable (FName, LName, PHON) VALUES ('".$FName."','".$LName."','".$PHON."')";`

Answer (score 2):

Please use `PDO` because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated ..

For your problem, you use `$_GET` and not `$_POST`, also you misspelled your variables (`$FNLame`):

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_Client;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$FName = $_GET['FName'];
$LName = $_GET['LName'];
$PHON = $_GET['PHON'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `ClientTable`(ID, FName, LName, PHON) VALUES (0,:FName,:LName,:PHON)");
$stmt->execute(array(':FName' => $FName, ':LName' => $LName, ':PHON' => $PHON));

echo "Database Update with:" .$FName. " " .$LName. " " .$PHON;
```

Comment: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving https://www.website.co/update.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

you are checking `$_POST['PHON']`, while in Query string you are passing

> https://www.website.com/update.php?FName=asdd&PHONE=4444444444.

Please correct PHONE first. then check

and get it like

```
$_GET['PHONE']
```

or

```
$_REQUEST['PHONE']
```

Comment: Also, it should be get, not post.

Answer (score 1):

May be sql error due to quotes (*'* or *""*). To avoid this, you can use something like

```
    $FName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FName']);
    $FNLame = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FLame']);
    $PHON = $_POST['PHON'];
```

Answer (score 0):

is your username and password correct? default for the majority of localhost is root and no password